# Link and svg path releationship

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

please help me, I created a custom map using svg paths. How can I create relationship between link and depanding path on the map. So when I hover the link, that path change fill color. 
This is the example of map.
[image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2xro7hskxchnxpo/c9c71005-cfed-40b7-a161-ab938a45b4c3.pnghttps://www.dropbox.com/s/2xro7hskxchnxpo/c9c71005-cfed-40b7-a161-ab938a45b4c3.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if that's what you want https://jsfiddle.net/grabantot/s6cjwxk1/1/.
It uses jquery and svg.js for simplicity but I hope you get the idea.

```
for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++) {
    var line = lines[i];
  (function(line) {
        $('#svg').before('<p id="l'+ i + '">line_' + i + '</p>')
    console.log($('l'+i))
    $('#l'+i).hover(function() {
        line.attr({'stroke':'#00F', 'stroke-width':8})
    }, function() {
        line.attr({'stroke':'#f00', 'stroke-width':5})
    })
  })(line)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you do is right-click on the svg file, choose edit with notepad++, than copy it to wathever ide you are using. Afterwards just enclose the  with  tags like this

```
<a href="...">
<path d="...">
</a>
```

Finally just edit the css style

```
svg { height: 50vw; }
path { fill: #d3d3d3; transition: .6s fill; }
path:hover { fill: #eee; }
```

I hope this helps

There is also a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2TM63ing6jY) that perfectly shows how to do this

And you can find the code on this [site](http://www.creativebloq.com/netmag/create-responsive-svg-image-maps-51411831)

PS: your image link doesnt work

Comment: Thank you for helping but grabantot solved my problem.